# How to access the second to last row of a csv file using python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Want to know if I can access the second to last row of this csv file?
Am able to access the very last using:

```
pd.DataFrame(file1.iloc[-1:,:].values)
```

But want to know how I can access the one right before the last?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


url1 = r"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/vaccinations/country_data/Austria.csv"

file1 = pd.read_csv(url1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(file1.iloc[:,:].values)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(file1.iloc[-1:,:].values)


Austria_date = df1.iloc[:,1]

Austria_cum = df1.iloc[:, 4].map('{:,}'.format)


if ( Austria_cum.iloc[0] == 'nan' ):
```

Essentially I am checking if the the row at that specific col is 'nan', which is True, and after which I want to get the data from the row right before the last. Please, how would this be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as that :

```py
df1.iloc[-2,:]
```

Comment: Thanks. It is throwing this error when I use it:     raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: Can't be unless your dataset has less than 2 rows.

Comment: Sorry, this works great. Only issue is that it prints two dates instead of one as well as an extra datatype. I receive this: 




```0    2021-02-14```
```1    2021-02-15```
```Name: 1, dtype: object```
```0    374,034.0```
```1          nan```
```Name: 4, dtype: object```

Comment: @JohnReese23487 If you refer to my solution It solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

To access the data frame at any index you can use the following

```
df.iloc[i]
```

For your ask you need to set the index as -2, which would look like this:

```
df.iloc[-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use negative indices like in your example, but pull out the second to last with `-2` instead of the last:

```
df.iloc[-2,:]
```

Comment: Thank you. I am receiving error code:     raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: Apologies, this does work, ths df.iloc[-2,:]. However, it prints an extra date and the "nan" type string too. So when I print it gives me this: 

```0    2021-02-14```
```1    2021-02-15```
```Name: 1, dtype: object```
```0    374,034.0```
```1          nan```
```Name: 4, dtype: object```

Comment: Its printing multiple rows because Im guessing you're using `df.iloc[-2:,:]` instead of `df.iloc[-2,:]`?

Comment: the extra `:` will give you all rows from the second to last to the end of the dataframe (which would be 2 rows)

Comment: Using the line: ```df.iloc[-2,:]``` throws the error IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds. Whereas the line: ```df.iloc[-2:,:]``` gives the extra date and datatype. Not sure why this is happening...

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with my IF-statement logic?:


```if (Austria_cum.iloc[0] == 'nan') :```
```df1 = pd.DataFrame(file1.iloc[:,:].values)```
```df1 = pd.DataFrame(file1.iloc[-2:,:].values)```
```Austria_date = df1.iloc[:,1]```
```Austria_cum = df1.iloc[:, 4].map('{:,}'.format)```
 ```print(Austria_date)```
 ```print(Austria_cum)```

Comment: well first of all that `if` statement is formatted incorrectly for python. second, when you pull out a row using `df1 = pd.DataFrame(file1.iloc[-1:,:].values)`, then `df1` will be a series. Later you use `Austria_cum = df1.iloc[:, 4]` with multiple indices to pull from a series, which won't work. Instead you can just remove the `:` ... `df1.iloc[4]`